# emacs run shell command against the buffer-file-name

Tags: emacs

In emacs I always have the need to run a command to validate the file.

I want to run a shell command against the file I am editing in the buffer
how should I do that ?

the shell command ( I wrote using python ) only accept file names as  argument.
so probably two solutions:

1. how do I pass the file-name in the mini-buffer to the command ?
2. how do I change the script so that it can accept the buffer region as input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Emacs variables to minibuffer shell commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121944/passing-emacs-variables-to-minibuffer-shell-commands)

Comment: If you are validating a file you may wish to look into flymake - it does what you describe.  It periodically and automatically runs a shell command against the content of the buffer being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is an exact duplicate. See link above.
2. You can use <kbd>M-|</kbd> to pass the region as input to any shell script. Assuming your script can read from stdin, that should resolve that option. (And if it can't, fixing that would certainly warrant a separate question.)

Comment: I modified the script to read from <STDIN>, that's much convenient.