# Emacs equivalent to VIM's `%`?

Tags: shell, vim, emacs

In VIM, One can use `%` to indicate the current filename when invoking a shell command. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of documentation showing what the equivalent is in emacs?

Comment: [buffer-file-name](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html)

Comment: there is no equivalent in Emacs.  `buffer-file-name` is an Elisp variable, and cannot be used at the shell command prompt.

Comment: Cross-linking with [Passing Emacs variables to minibuffer shell commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121944/passing-emacs-variables-to-minibuffer-shell-commands) (which is basically a duplicate, except that the two questions are coming from notably different angles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one.  But this is Emacs!  So here:

```
(defun my-shell-command-on-current-file (command &optional output-buffer error-buffer)
  "Run a shell command on the current file (or marked dired files).
In the shell command, the file(s) will be substituted wherever a '%' is."
  (interactive (list (read-from-minibuffer "Shell command: "
                                           nil nil nil 'shell-command-history)
                     current-prefix-arg
                     shell-command-default-error-buffer))
  (cond ((buffer-file-name)
         (setq command (replace-regexp-in-string "%" (buffer-file-name) command nil t)))
        ((and (equal major-mode 'dired-mode) (save-excursion (dired-move-to-filename)))
         (setq command (replace-regexp-in-string "%" (mapconcat 'identity (dired-get-marked-files) " ") command nil t))))
  (shell-command command output-buffer error-buffer))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-!") 'my-shell-command-on-current-file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this whenever the minibuffer expects you to type something (caveat: does not work with ido, but obviously you can always get out of that with e.g. C-x C-f).  You can also use it in regular buffers.

```
(defun insert-filename-or-buffername (&optional arg)
  "If the buffer has a file, insert the base name of that file.
  Otherwise insert the buffer name.  With prefix argument, insert the full file name."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((buffer (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window)))
         (file-path-maybe (buffer-file-name buffer)))
    (insert (if file-path-maybe
                (if arg
                    file-path-maybe
                  (file-name-nondirectory file-path-maybe))
              (buffer-name buffer)))))

(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-c f") 'insert-filename-or-buffername)
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, using the emacs 24 gui version from homebrew.... I see the filename as the 3rd item in from the bottom left corner of the (minor)-mode-bar, just above the mini-buffer.

To see where i am, using ido-mode i just do `C-x C-f` No config needed there.